# flaskform pass a variable (WTForms)

Tags: python, flask, wtforms

I want to pass a str to be used as the prompt for a form. I thought it would be simple but it is proving to be difficult.

Here is my code:

```
class PostForm(FlaskForm):
    post = TextAreaField(Question, validators=[DataRequired()])
    submit = SubmitField('Submit')`
```

And,

```
form = PostForm('my question')
```

the corresponding html

```
{{ wtf.quick_form(form) }}
```

Comment: Similar to your answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/51112483/5320906

Answer (score 1):

So, I still don't have an answer to the question, but I did manage to come up with a solution.

```
class PostForm(FlaskForm):
    post = TextAreaField(_l('This no longer matters'), validators=[DataRequired()])
    submit = SubmitField(_l('Submit'))
```

And then in the routes

```
from wtforms.fields.core import Label
form = PostForm()
form.post.label = Label("post", 'Real question goes here')}
```

The explanation for this is that TextAreaField creates a label attribute on post that is accessible and changable, but it needs to be formated correctly as a Label object from wtforms.fields.core. (Simply reassigning it as a string did not work). The representation of this object is:

```
<label for="post">Real question goes here</label>
```

And it is of type

```
<class 'wtforms.fields.core.Label'>
```

Comment: You can also do `form.post.label.text = f'{<whatever>}'`

Answer (score 1):

Today I'm figured out about a similar problem as yours. I wanted to pass a variable to `FlaskForm`. For a small CV creation app, I want to give the user an opportunity to create more than 1 entry for his work experience and I wanted to do it with `FieldList` and `FormField`. And I needed to do it on one page so in one form.

My solution is pretty simple python implementation of factory pattern for forms:

```py
class ConstructorForm(FlaskForm):
    ...
    work_experience_form = FieldList(FormField(WorkExperienceForm), min_entries=1, max_entries=1)
    skills_form = FieldList(FormField(SkillsForm), min_entries=1, max_entries=1)
    ...
```

And here is my function for building extending forms:

```py
def constructor_form(work_experience_forms=1, skills_forms=1):
    class _ConstructorForm(ConstructorForm):
        pass

    _ConstructorForm.work_experience_form = FieldList(
        FormField(WorkExperienceForm), min_entries=work_experience_forms, max_entries=work_experience_forms
    )
    _ConstructorForm.skills_form = FieldList(
        FormField(SkillsForm), min_entries=skills_forms, max_entries=skills_forms
    )

    return _ConstructorForm()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def PostForm(question)
    class F(Flaskform):
        post = TextAreaField(question, validators=[DataRequired()])
        submit = SubmitField('Submit')
    return F()
```