# Pass variable to FlaskForm

Tags: python-3.x, flask-wtforms, wtforms

So I have this FlaskForm.

```
class MyForm(FlaskForm):
   input = StringField(
      "Some pretty label",
      validators: [
          Length(
             min=10,
             max=20,
             message="Must be between {min} and {max}"
          )
      ]
   )

# route /<language_code>/login
login_form = LoginForm()
```

So now I want to pass a variable to show the form in another language. The route is language specific so the same form has to show in the correct language. I made a Library which hold (Language) Dictionaries:

```
class Library(object):
    def __init__(self):
        languages = db.query(Language) \
            .with_entities(Language.code) \
            .filter(Language.active==True) \
            .all()

        for language_code, in languages:
            setattr(self, language_code, Dictionary(language_code=language_code))

    def get(self, key, **kwargs):
        return self.__dict__[key]

class Dictionary(object):
    def __init__(self, language_code):
        self.language_code = language_code
        texts = db.query(Text) \
            .with_entities(Text.key, Text.text) \
            .filter(Text.language_code==self.language_code) \
            .all()

        for key, text in texts:
            setattr(self, key, text)

    def __getattr__(self, key):
        try:
            return self.__dict__[key]
        except KeyError:
            return '[{lc}~{key}]'.format(lc = self.language_code, key = key)

    def get(self, key, **kwargs):
        try:
            text = self.__dict__[key]
            for key, value in kwargs.items():
                text = text.replace('{' + key + '}', str(value))
            return text
        except KeyError:
            return '[{lc}~{key}]'.format(lc = self.language_code, key = key)

TextLibrary = Library()
```

I like it this way because I can use it in many ways:

```
TextLibrary.en.some_key
//outputs value of English key 'some_key'

Text = TextLibrary.get('en')
// defines English Dictionary

Text.name
// prints 'Your name'

Text.get('length_between', min=10, max=150)
// prints 'error: length must be between 10 and 150'
```

To make this happen I madehave this data structure (from db but for now just plain).
`Text.get('<language_code>').<key> = <value>` (which is in TextLibrary)

Now I want to make this happen:

```
class MyForm(FlaskForm):

   Text = TextLibrary.get(language_code)

   input = StringField(
      Text.name,
      validators: [
          Length(
             min=10,
             max=20,
             message=Text.get('length_between', min=10, max=20)
          )
      ]
   )

# route /<language_code>/login
login_form = LoginForm(language_code=language_code)
```

I know I can't just pass some parameter to it. I've tried lots of things but I can't seem to figure out how I could pass the language_code (or anything for that matter) to `MyForm`.

PS: If this somehow looks like I'm asking something like:
[flaskform pass a variable (WTForms)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51181324/flaskform-pass-a-variable-wtforms) or 
[Pass to and use a variable inside a FlaskForm (WTForms)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47621904/pass-to-and-use-a-variable-inside-a-flaskform-wtforms) then you are wrong or I'm a bad explainer :)

Comment: Have you seen the [Internationalization (i18n)](https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/2.3.x/i18n/#internationalization-i18n) documentation? There is an example of using a form's meta class to do runtime translations; `form = MyForm(request.form, meta={'locales': ['en_US', 'en']})`. You can use your own translation provider too.

Comment: Nope. I did not. For some reason never encountered that part. I will dive it to it. Thanks!